# Issues uninstalling amdgpu-dkms after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management

I'm having some issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 (from 22.10).  I had the proprietary AMD drivers installed for my video card, and after the upgrade the amdgpu-dkms package is causing me apt errors:

```
$ sudo amdgpu-uninstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcc-11-base libasan6 libdrm-dev libelf-dev libgcc-11-dev libncurses-dev libomxil-bellagio-bin libomxil-bellagio0 libpciaccess-dev libstdc++-11-dev libtinfo-dev
  libtsan0 zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amdgpu-core* amdgpu-dkms* amdgpu-dkms-firmware* amdgpu-lib* amdgpu-lib32* comgr* gst-omx-amdgpu* hip-runtime-amd* hsa-rocr* hsa-rocr-dev* hsakmt-roct-dev*
  libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1* libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386* libdrm-amdgpu-common* libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1* libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386* libdrm2-amdgpu* libdrm2-amdgpu:i386*
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa* libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386* libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers* libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386* libgbm1-amdgpu* libgbm1-amdgpu:i386*
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri* libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386* libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx* libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386* libglapi-amdgpu-mesa* libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386*
  libllvm15.0.50403-amdgpu* libllvm15.0.50403-amdgpu:i386* libxatracker2-amdgpu* libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386* mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers* mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers*
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386* mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers* mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386* openmp-extras-runtime* rocm-core* rocm-hip-runtime* rocm-language-runtime*
  rocm-llvm* rocm-ocl-icd* rocm-opencl* rocm-opencl-runtime* rocminfo* xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 49 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,382 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'amdgpu-dkms-firmware' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 345517 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing amdgpu-dkms (1:5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04) ...
Deleting module amdgpu-5.18.13-1538762.22.04 completely from the DKMS tree.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic
grep: /boot/config-5.19.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
W: zstd compression (CONFIG_RD_ZSTD) not supported by kernel, using gzip
grep: /boot/config-5.19.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
E: gzip compression (CONFIG_RD_GZIP) not supported by kernel
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--remove):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm trying to uninstall all the proprietary AMD GPU drivers, but I don't seem to be able to.  The uninstall script is complaining about some missing headers (grep: /boot/config-5.19.0-38-generic: No such file or directory), which I think were uninstalled as part of the upgrade, and are not available in the 23.04 repos.  I managed to install them by hand, but I'm still seeing the same error.

At the moment, my goal is to uninstall the drivers entirely, but I don't know how to force it to remove the package.  I could also be looking at this wrong, and there's a better solution.  Can anyone suggest anything that could help here?

Current Kernel:

```
$ uname -r
6.2.0-20-generic
```

Apt Cache:

```
$ apt-cache policy amdgpu amdgpu-dkms
amdgpu:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:5.4.50403-1538762.22.04
  Version table:
     1:5.4.50403-1538762.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.3/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
amdgpu-dkms:
  Installed: 1:5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04
  Candidate: 1:5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04
  Version table:
 *** 1:5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.3/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.3/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

DKMS Status:

```
$ dkms status
openrazer-driver/3.5.1, 5.19.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
openrazer-driver/3.5.1, 5.19.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
openrazer-driver/3.5.1, 6.2.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: @Nmath Well, I got better performance in games with the proprietary ones.  There was no issue installing them, but I installed them on 22.10, before the upgrade.

Comment: I can barely believe that a big company such as AMD doesn't want to offer drivers for the latest Ubuntu.  For them it should be pretty easy to make.

Answer (score 7):

A friend offered some advice, and we managed to get it working!  In my case, this was the fix:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq amdgpu-dkms
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm amdgpu-dkms.*
sudo apt -f install
```

From there I was able to run `sudo amdgpu-uninstall` to uninstall the rest of the packages.  Thanks folks!

Comment: I would suggest to combine the "cd" with the "rm".

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/amdgpu-dkms.*